# Unexpected output from Console.Write in Linqpad

Tags: c#, linqpad

This appears to be an issue with LinqPad.

When using Console.Write with an empty string, in the Results pane a carriage return and linefeed are inserted instead. This does not happen in a Console project using Visual Studio.

**Additional Information**
Looking at the source for the Results pane in Linqpad, I see this:

```
<body><div id='final'>Hello|World|<br />|Hello|World</div></body>
```

So it appears that a break is being inserted for some reason.

LinqPad version: v5.22.00 beta

Test code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Hello");
    Console.Write("|");
    Console.Write("World");
    Console.Write("|");
    Console.Write("");   //Writing an empty string
    Console.Write("|");
    Console.Write("Hello");
    Console.Write("|");
    Console.Write("World");
}
```

Actual output:

Hello|World|
|Hello|World

Expected output:

Hello|World||Hello|World

Comment: What happens if you do `Console.Write(string.Empty);`? Same thing?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing.  I also ran the code on version 4.0 and it produced the same output

Comment: Sounds like a problem with LinqPad if that's what you are seeing. You should post on their forums, which it [looks like you already have](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1293/unexpected-output-with-console-write)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be reported to  the LinqPad devs.

Comment: @DarrenYoung - Yes that is true and I adjusted my script to check for that.  I discovered it when code that was running in a loop was printing the result of a method call that was returning an empty string occasionally.

Comment: @MattBurland - I can't disagree with that.  I paused before posting this question here but ultimately decided to post because the Linqpad support page indicated that Linqpad questions are answered here.  If the question gets closed, so be it.  I can see how the question might be too specific and not a great fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in the 5.22.05 beta.